# Show that $H_s$ is subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $S$ be any subset of a group $G$. Show that $H_s = \{x \in G\mid xs = sx \text{ for  all } s \in S\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $e$, the identity element of the group $\in$ $H_S$ as $es=se\ \forall s\in S$. Now let $x\in H_S$ $\Rightarrow$ $xs=sx$ $\Rightarrow$ $x^{-1}xs=x^{-1}sx$ and hence $sx^{-1}=x^{-1}s$ $\forall s\in S$, so $x^{-1}\in H_S$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: I'll start you off $e \in H_s$ since $es=se=s, \forall s \in S$.

Comment: please give me more detail hint..